# CDI - Injection Point over method and fields

Tags: cdi

I'm new on CDI, I was reading the Weld specification
http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/index.html

in the chapter four i understand the Injection points, easy!, but in method initializier and direct field always I must to have a class attribute from another class? See the examples:

```
public class Checkout {

   private final ShoppingCart cart;

   @Inject
   public Checkout(ShoppingCart cart) {
      this.cart = cart;
   }
}
```

and

```
public class Checkout {
   private @Inject ShoppingCart cart;
}
```

Always attribute from a class, not type data like String, Integer, etc?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You can use the wrapper types in your code as injectable resources, you just need to make a producer method for them and they need to be qualified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String, Integer, etc classes with qualifiers as well. For example using @Named annotation or by providing your own qualifier annotation.